# chart.js: segment true is not working in labels outside pie chart : chart.piecelabel.js

Tags: charts, chart.js, segment

Here, I've used chart.js and chart.piecelabel.js to add a segment to the pie chart... but an arrow isn't added.

```
       options: {
             pieceLabel: {
                    render: function (args) {
                    const label = args.label,
                    value = args.value;
                    return label + '\n' + value;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I also added  fontColor: '#6e6f6f',
                    position: 'outside',
                    segment: true,
                    fontSize: xAxisFontSize-2,
                    overlap: true

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `chart.piecelabel.js` has updated their syntax. Their latest versions no longer use `pieceLabel` but a `plugin: labels:` stanza.

```
 options: {
     plugins: {
       labels: {
         render: function (args) {
           const label = args.label,
                 value = args.value;
           return label + '\n' + value;
         }
       }
     }
   }
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/d047bqzo/5/

Comment: Labels Should be outside the pie chart with arrow and should not be overlapped. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIXjJ.png